# Не запускаеться PyQt designer

Tags: python

Не запускаеться PyQt designer (Qt Designer)
Всегда работал отлично, но в один момент перестал запускатся, вообще, никаких ошибок, даже в диспетчере задач его нету. Пробовал переустановить питон и заново скачать, не работает, пробовал скачать отдельно Qt Designer, та же проблема
Windows 10 64x

Comment: посмотрите в журнале событий по идее пишут даже невидимые ошибки http://netler.ru/ikt/windows10-events.htm

Comment: `pip install pyqt5-tools` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832661/installing-pyqt5-designer-on-windows